# Expandable listview child node as a web page link

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

Expandable listview child node as a web page link and then link should be replaced with other text but when a user click on that child node it get the result as a web page.

Let me explain you by an example

1. List item

   subitem 1

   subitem 2

   subitem 3

   2. List item

   subitem 11

   subitem 22

   subitem 33

but these sub items are overloaded by a link 
if a user click on a particular sub item then it get open a particular web page related to that sum item.

Comment: please share any code you've written and having problem with :)

Comment: public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                                        int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id)




            {

                if(groupPosition>=0)
                {
                    if(childPosition>=0)
                    {
                        String url = "http://www.example.com";
                        Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                        startActivity(i);
                    }